# ASP.NET & Bootstrap: input type="text" with width:100% does not span the whole width of the div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have a question about HTML and CSS behaviour.
I have HTML and CSS produced using ASP.NET Web Forms and Bootstrap.

The ASP.NET code snippet is :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="txtUser">Email : </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <%-- asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" TextMode="Email" Width="100%"></--%>
            <input type="email" id="txtUser" name="txtUser" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="txtPassword">Password : </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is where I have a ASP TextBox or HTML input type="text"
 that has width of 100%, but its width does not span the whole `div class="col-md-4"`.

I used firebug to investigate, this is the result:
[firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5pPc.png)
as you can see, none of the textbox span 100% of the width of the `div class="col-md-4"`

Can anyone explain to me as why is to this ?

Comment: does style="width: 100% !important; padding: 0 !important;" help?

Comment: can you show your runnig code in snippet?

Comment: I saw the rules on firebug, the `col-md-4` also has padding 15px to left and right, and also `float:left`, but the resulting textbox is still far from 100% and skewed vr much to the left. I have shown it the firebug image on there. Idk how to make a running snippet yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `max-width` style in `Site.css` file that limits the `Width` for all TextBoxs, you can just remove or comment it.

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```